# How to move through fragments using back-/next-buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently programming my first app, and I want to modify my Tabbed Activity so that the user can navigate between the fragments using back- and next-buttons and not by swiping.

The fragments are used for user interaction and hold some dynamically filled textViews and radioButtons. I've tried to change to a specific fragment when I click the button 'fab' with the following code, but that doesn't work as I just get a blank fragment:

```
// Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
// primary sections of the activity.
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

// Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

How do I move forward and backward through the fragments using buttons? I assume that it is better to declare those buttons in the activity and not in the fragment, isn't it? What do I need to change in the onClick method of those Buttons?

Answer (score 0):

on the next button write this

```
 NextFragment fragment = new NextFragment();
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(NextFragment.class.toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

on previous button simply write this

```
    getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```